# How to add *xaml.cs files to Coverage Results Filters?

Tags: c#, rider, dotcover

[image]
I've tried `**\*.xaml.cs` and `**\*View*\**\*.xaml.cs` but dotCover still picking up those `.xaml.cs` files.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude file masks should be able to filter them out.

[image]